# No matching distribution found for Install

Tags: scikit-learn, pip

While trying to install `scikit-learn` using the command:

```
python -m pip install scikit-learn
```

It's throwing an error as:

> Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement for install(From versions:)
> No matching distribution found for install

However, in the `site_packages` folder the file `install.py` is present.
**How to remove this issue?**

Comment: There is a typo in your post: it should be `scikit-learn`, not `sckit-learn`. Is this typo related to the error you saw?

Answer (score 10):

I know this is an old post, but this same issue kept bugging me for a long time so sharing this in case any other lost soul reaches here. I got it working by using python3 -m pip :

```
python3 -m pip install scikit-learn
```

Answer (score 1):

Configuring pip over Proxy was bit tedious in my case too.
Here's an alternative solution.

Use the Ubuntu Package Manager, after setting the proxy in apt config file using https://askubuntu.com/questions/89437/how-to-install-packages-with-apt-get-on-a-system-connected-via-proxy

```
    sudo apt-get install python-sklearn
```